# VBA to use Checkbox Selection for Multiple cases

Tags: vba, excel

I have designed an userform with 7checkboxes. Each Checkbox has an call function, which is called as autofilter. This function autofilter, helps to filter the field 4 in my sheet and Displays the result.

Here, I have 3 cases.

Case1. when Checkbox1 is selected,  Display the result of autofilter1.

case2: when checkboxes1 and 2 are selected, Display the result of autofilter1 and 2.

Note: it is not necessary that user can select just checkboxes 1 and 2, it can be checkbox 2 and 3 or 1 and 3 as well or sometime all 3 selection.

Case3: when nothing is selected, clear the filter.

I am successful in generating the case1 Situation, How should I proceed, in order to achieve case2 and case3.

Below is the autofilter function, which is assigned to checkbox1.

```
Sub autofilter1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
wslr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set myfilt = ws.Range("A1:D" & wslr)
myfilt.autofilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
"USA"
End Sub
```

autofilter function assigned to checkbox2.

```
Sub autofilter2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
wslr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set myfilt = ws.Range("A1:D" & wslr)
myfilt.autofilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
"Germany"
End Sub
```

autofilter function assigned to Checkbox 3.

```
Sub autofilter3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result_APQP")
wslr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set myfilt = ws.Range("A1:D" & wslr)
myfilt.autofilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
"France"
End Sub
```

In the Command Button, "Go", I have the following code,

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Call autofilter1
End If
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Call autofilter2
End If
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
Call autofiletr3
End If
End Sub
```

I have attached the Image also, for reference. In the Image, i have just taken the example for 3 Checkbox. 
[image: This is the example of case1, where one Checkbox is selected and the displays the result of autofilter1.]
[image: This is the example of case2, where the checkbox1 and 2 are selected and Displays the result of autofilter1 and 2.]
[image: Case3, is where nothing is selected and it Displays the original sheet, Clearing the filter.]

Comment: next time sumarize a little plz, just ask the basis problem. Make a sub for each case, and ´select case true : case checkbox1.value : sub1: case check2: sub2 .....end select´ . Sorry i am on phone app, can't format the code better.

Comment: ya, next time i would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code for a UserForm module.

I made a UserForm with 3 checkboxes.

Each event handler just fires the `DoFilter()` method, which checks the checkboxes and for the ones that are true, builds string array based on their `Caption` (as in your example pictures) and passes that Array to the AutoFilter. If the Array is empty, the autofilter gets disabled.

**Edit:**
In the Visual Basic Editor (ALT+F11), in the Project window right-click. In the menu select `Insert -> UserForm`. On this UserForm, add a number of CheckBoxes. For each checkbox, change the `Caption` property in the Properties window to a value that you want to display in the filtered range, e.g. `CheckBox1.Caption` would be "USA" as per the question. Next, Right-click on the userform module and select `View Code`. In the code window, paste everything below:

```
Private Sub DoFilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strCriteria() As String
Dim arrIdx As Integer

Dim cBox As Control

arrIdx = 0
For Each cBox In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cBox) = "CheckBox" Then
        If cBox.Value = True Then
            ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)
            strCriteria(arrIdx) = cBox.Caption
            arrIdx = arrIdx + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cBox

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
If arrIdx = 0 Then
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
Else
    ws.Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change() 'Repeat for each CheckBox on your form.
    DoFilter
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Change() 'Repeat for each CheckBox on your form.
    DoFilter
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_Change() 'Repeat for each CheckBox on your form.
    DoFilter
End Sub
```

**Additional Edit:**N.b. in this case the filter will trigger as soon as you change the checkbox. If you want to apply the filter on the click of a commandbutton, you can also put the following code in the UserForm module, instead of the `Private Sub CheckBox#_Change()`

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    DoFilter
End Sub
```

You might want to use a [Control Array](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/) in order not to have each `CheckBox_Change` event handler seperately listed.

Comment: can you tell me where we add this Private Sub do filter() , is it in module  ?

Comment: In the userform in this case.

Comment: means, userform click()

Comment: Ì am not getting an clear Background idea for this code. could you Please explain more in detail

Comment: Can you upload an working sheet, It will be easy for me to understand , rather explaining in words. My VBA knowledge is basic

Comment: See Edits. Just jam all the code in the UserForm module. Right click on UserForm - View code. It's where you currently have the `CommandButton4_Click()`.

Comment: The code is not having any error, but due to some reason, I am not able to see my result.

Comment: Have you changed the line `Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")` to point to the sheet you're trying to filter?

Comment: @ Rik sportel, sorry, I missed some letters in caption, now  it is working fine :) sorry and Thank you

Comment: Yeah the Captions in this example are equal to the values you wish to filter on. Anyway - if it fixes your problem, then consider accepting the answer. Cheers and happy to help! You're welcome.

Comment: @ Rik Sportel, I have a button in the worksheet, how will i assign this macro , LAst question

Comment: Create a regular module, with `Sub OpenForm() : UserForm1.Show : End Sub` From the macro window (ALT+F8) you can call the `OpenForm` that displays the form with the Checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time and helping me to solve it

Comment: No problem. If your question is answered, please mark this one as such. Good luck in your endeavors.

Comment: What if we have an table in the sheet, ? I have added the listobjects("Table Name").range.autofilter. Still, i am getting an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148331/discussion-between-rik-sportel-and-mikz).